# BeautifulSoup: grab all content of all <ul> after each header

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a long, long list of headers which are followed by lists:

```
<h2>Header1</h2>
<ul>
<li>A</li>
<li>B</li>
<li>C</li>
</ul>
<h2>Header2</h2>
<ul>
<li>D</li>
<li>E</li>
<li>F</li>
</ul>
```

Et cetera. What is the most compact way of grabbing all the lists after each header using `BeautifulSoup` and corresponding header?

So ideally the result would be a dictionary, looking like:

```py
{
'header1': ['A','B','C'],
'header2': ['D','E','F'],
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this for start and optimize after you get the idea.

```
import bs4

txt = '''\
<h2>Header1</h2>
<ul>
<li>A</li>
<li>B</li>
<li>C</li>
</ul>
<h2>Header2</h2>
<ul>
<li>D</li>
<li>E</li>
<li>F</li>
</ul>
'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(txt)

output = dict()

key = []

for _ in soup.findAll('h2'):
  key.append(_.findAll(text=True)[0])

vec = [j.findAll('li') for j in soup.findAll('ul')]

for i in range(len(vec)):
  output[key[i]] = []
  for j in vec[i]:
    output[key[i]].append(j.findAll(text=True)[0])

print(output)
```

Output

```
{'Header1': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Header2': ['D', 'E', 'F']}
```

Edited:
Shorter and neater code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''\
<h2>Header1</h2>
<ul>
<li>A</li>
<li>B</li>
<li>C</li>
</ul>
<h2>Header2</h2>
<ul>
<li>D</li>
<li>E</li>
<li>F</li>
</ul>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')
output = dict()
header = soup.find_all('h2')

for num in range(len(header)):
  temp = header[num]
  key = temp.find_all(text=True)[0]
  output[key] = []

  for item in (soup.find_all('ul')[num]).find_all('li'):
    output[key].append(item.find_all(text=True)[0])

print(output)
```

Output will be the same

```
{'Header1': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Header2': ['D', 'E', 'F']}
```

Answer (score 3):

If headers are unique you could use `:has` with adjacent sibling combinator to be sure there is an `ul` immediately following the `h2`, and then `:contains` to get the right `ul li` combo after the `h2` within a dict comprehension. More compact than the other solutions so far. Requires bs4 4.7.1+

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<h2>Header1</h2>
<ul>
<li>A</li>
<li>B</li>
<li>C</li>
</ul>
<h2>Header2</h2>
<ul>
<li>D</li>
<li>E</li>
<li>F</li>
</ul>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
d = {i.text:[j.text for j in soup.select(f'h2:contains("{i.text}") + ul li')] for i in soup.select('h2:has(+ul)')}
print(d)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@QuantStats solution will work, but I believe this one can be slightly more compact:

```py
txt = '''\
<h2>Header1</h2>
<ul>
<li>A</li>
<li>B</li>
<li>C</li>
</ul>
<h2>Header2</h2>
<ul>
<li>D</li>
<li>E</li>
<li>F</li>
</ul>
'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

output = {}
for i in soup.findAll('h2'):
    k = i.text
    ul = i.findNext('ul')
    v = [li.text for li in ul.findAll('li')]
    output[k] = v

print(output)
```

Comment: @David Pekker This solution is better. +1 from me.